# Can not connect to Oracle Database: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException

Tags: java, database, oracle, database-connection

its not possible to connect to the Oracle Database. The database is running and i get the following error when i try to ping the database from Eclipse.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Fehler: 
The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:478)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:547)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:29)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:556)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.database.connectivity.db.OracleJDBCConnection.createConn(OracleJDBCConnection.java:193)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.database.connectivity.db.OracleJDBCConnection.createConnection(OracleJDBCConnection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.database.connectivity.db.OracleJDBCConnectionFactory.createConnection(OracleJDBCConnectionFactory.java:26)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:372)
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:419)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:873)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:258)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1577)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:353)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:206)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:120)
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:350)
... 20 more
```

The configuration is the following:

[image: This is the configuration]

Iam complete new to the Oracle Database. So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying exception is this:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

That means that there was nothing listening for the database connection.  Some of the possible explanations are:

- You are connecting to the wrong host.
- You are using the wrong port
- The database is not running at the moment
- There is firewall blocking your access, and "refusing" the connections.

I note that you have set the host to "localhost".  That will only work if your Java client is running on the same host as the database.

Comment: ok do you have any recipes for this? The firewall is not blocking it.

Comment: Can you prove that?   Can you successfully connect using the Oracle SQL tool?  One the client machine?  Using that "localhost" and that port 1512?